# Analyze survey data in R

Tags: r, survey

which package and fuction do you use to analyze survey data in R?
I'm mostly interested in calculating `percentages` for `single choice` and `multiple choice` questions. Also, filtering data by `target groups`.

`single choice` questions looks more clear.
However, how do you deal with `multiple choice` questions (when question is in more than one column)?
F.e., question `Pet` is in 3 separate columns.

Also, is there an easy way to switch between `original` data and `weighted` data?

```
df =data.frame(
  c(1,1,1,1, 1 ),
  c(0.99, 1.21, 0.83, 0.82, 2.3),
  c(16, 25, 34, 45, 74),
  c("Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female"),
  c("Dog", "", "Dog", "", ""),
  c("Cat", "Cat", "", "Cat", "Cat"),
  c("", "Fish", "", "", "Fish")
)


names(df) = c("Respondent", "Weight", "Age","Gender","Pet_Dog", "Pet_Cat", "Pet_Fish")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give an answer by specifying the building blocks for what you're trying to do. Starting with the weights question first: The way you use your `Weight` column is baked into how you call your functions. For instance, the `table()` function from `base` R can provide you with totals of each category in a given variable:

```
table(df$Gender)

## Female   Male 
##      2      3
```

For the weighted version, you could use, e.g., `wtd.table()` from `questionr`:

```
library(questionr)
wtd.table(df$Gender, weights = df$Weight)

## Female   Male 
##   3.13   3.02
```

And for simplicity, you could use `wtd.table()` to give the *unweighted* totals by omitting the weights parameter:

```
wtd.table(df$Gender)

## Female   Male 
##      2      3
```

For proportions, you can feed a `table` into `prop.table()`:

```
prop.table(wtd.table(df$Gender))

## Female   Male 
##    0.4    0.6 

prop.table(wtd.table(df$Gender, weight = df$Weight))

##    Female      Male 
## 0.5089431 0.4910569
```

Note from the documentation of `prop.table()` that this is just a convenience wrapper for dividing the table by the sum of its entries:

> This is really `sweep(x, margin, margin.table(x, margin), "/")` for newbies, except that if `margin` has length zero, then one gets `x/sum(x)`.

For filtering by subgroups, it's the same as always: use your favorite filtering tactic on the data frame, then run it through the above. For a `base` R option looking at the responses regarding fish from among the men:

```
with(df[df$Gender == "Male", ], prop.table(wtd.table(Pet_Fish, weights = Weight)))

##                Fish 
## 0.5993377 0.4006623
```

The interpretation is that 60% of the (weighted) responses on the fish question (among men) were blank and the other 40% indicated having a fish. If it were me, I'd recode those blanks to be "no fish" or "none" or something like that, but that's just my preference.

Another route, which you may have meant in your question, is to do crosstabs. You can achieve this with a two-way table, which you get by just supplying two variables in the `wtd.table()` function.

```
prop.table(wtd.table(df$Pet_Fish, df$Gender, weights = df$Weight), margin = 2)

##         Female      Male
##      0.2651757 0.5993377
## Fish 0.7348243 0.4006623
```

Here, `margin = 2` specifies that columns should sum up to 1. You could then glue multiple tables like this together, etc.

As for how to handle multi-choice questions, that's up to you. If responses were exclusive (i.e. nobody had two different kinds of pets) then it would be straightforward; just merge the variables together and use the techniques described above. Your dataframe does not have that property. One approach to consider is to leave them as binary variables and report on each answer independently; for instance, you could treat the pet question as being three separate questions (Dog Y/N, Cat Y/N, Fish Y/N). Alternatively, you could break the cases down into the 8 different possible combinations of pet ownership and recode the variable that way. There are many other ways to proceed and which is the best depends entirely on what you're trying to present in these data.

---

**EDIT:** For the multi-crosstabs question, I'd use a `cbind()` approach. As an example, I'll invent an `Age_recode` column so that I can work in a factor environment instead of a numeric one:

```
df$Age_recode <- c("Young", "Young", "Mid", "Mid", "Old")
```

A crosstab table with multiple factors could be something like this:

```
cbind(prop.table(wtd.table(df$Pet_Fish, df$Gender, weights = df$Weight), margin = 2),
      prop.table(wtd.table(df$Pet_Fish, df$Age_recode, weights = df$Weight), margin = 2))

##         Female      Male Mid Old Young
##      0.2651757 0.5993377   1   0  0.45
## Fish 0.7348243 0.4006623   0   1  0.55
```

This is obviously a bit cumbersome, so if it's something you want to do many times it would be advantageous to write a function to automate it. There may also be something in `questionr` that does this, but I don't know the full scope of what's in that library so I can't speak to that.

Note that in general, `cbind()` can be a bit risky to use because it will just blindly glue tables onto each other without respect for row names. In this case it's OK (I think), because the `wtd.table()`s will have row names that are just an alphabetical list of all responses found in the first variable passed into the function and the tables should match. (Again, I *think* I'm not missing anything here, but it's possible that I am.)

Comment: Package `questionr` is new for me and quite handy - `cross.multi.table` solves multiple choice question poblem easily. Code example below: https://pastebin.pl/view/2c5b2eb5
Is there any convenient way to add multiple demo questions to the function? F.e. To have `Age & Gender` together?

Comment: Managed to solve with 2 separate functions, maybe is there more convienient way?

Comment: Never mind -- I think the `cbind()` approach is OK after all, for reasons I detailed in my edit.